# Symlink and hide dotfiles

Tags: unix, dotfiles, ln

How could I rename a bunch of dotfiles and add the leading dot in the same command? I see people writing:

```
ln -s vimrc .vimrc
ln -s gitconfig .gitconfig
```

But I would like something like this:

`ln -s {vimrc,gitconfig} ~/.$1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `for` loop:

```
for f in vimrc gitconfig; do ln -s  $f .$f ; done
```

If you have the filename list in a file:

```
for f in `cat filename_list.txt`; do mv $f .$f ; done
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain to me what is wrong with my idea? Ideally I would like to avoid spending time on a similar error next time.

Comment: @mm2703, `ln -s {vimrc,gitconfig} ~/.$1` will be expanded to `ln -s vimrc gitconfig ~/.$1` (specifying multiple targets) only works if the link is directory. And `$1` is not defined. It will be replaced with the first comamnd line argument in the shell script, but with empty string not in shell script.